# Get second index value of ArrayList in JSTL without using any loop

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

As my subject elaborate about mu question, I have to use 2nd value of ArrayList in JSTL,. Lets say I have some list and I am adding values into it:

```
list.add("XXX");
list.add("YYY");
list.add("ZZZ");
```

So I have to print `ZZZ` in my JSP page using JSTL but without using any loop.

Please answer.

Comment: ankit if you know the index then access using it otherwise you need to iterate

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking for accessing a particular index of an `ArrayList`. You can do this  using array `[]` operator

```
<c:out value="${list[2]}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question (get second element) and your description (show "ZZZ") don't match. Assuming you want to reference the second element in the `ArrayList` list, you could simply use `list.get(2)`;

Answer (score 0):

Just use ${list[2]} to print the second element.